# Cannot get multiple lines to display correctly in ggplot line graph

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have data in the following format:

```
    Block    Condition    Value
    1        Red          66
    2        Red          34
    3        Red          48
    4        Red          55
    5        Red          63
    6        Red          23
    1        Blue         72
    2        Blue         28
    3        Blue         82
    4        Blue         44
    5        Blue         44
    6        Blue         32
    1        Yellow       22
    2        Yellow       24
    3        Yellow       54
    4        Yellow       18
    5        Yellow       27
    6        Yellow       66
```

I want to visualise it in a line graph, with Blocks 1-6 on the x-axis, Values on the y-axis, and Three lines coloured according to Condition. I tried:

```
    ggplot(data = df, aes(x=Block, y=Value, colour = Condition) +
    geom_line()
```

This resulted in an empty graph, i.e. Blocks placed on X axis, Values placed on y axis as intended, but no lines. When searching online I noticed some people had managed to solve it by converting the Condition from character to factor. I tried:

```
    ggplot(data = tacs, aes(x=Block, y=Value, colour 
    =as.factor(Condition))) +
     geom_line()
```

But this didn't work either. I am relatively new to R and was hoping somebody might be able to point me in the right direction. Thanks in advance!

Comment: In the first `ggplot` call, you are missing a parenthesis after Condition. Also, I can't reproduce your problem, when I add the missing parenthesis, the lines show up.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is missing a parenthesis. It should read like this:

```
 ggplot(data = df, aes(x=Block, y=Value, colour = Condition)) +
    geom_line()
```

It should produce this graph:

[image]

With the warning `geom_path: Each group consists of only one observation. Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?`

Not sure if this is what you want to plot since the lines aren't being plotted. The reason for this is that `aes()` needs to be specified for `geom_line()`, particularly `group=Condition`. If you use this code instead, you'll get a better graph with lines:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = Block, y = Value, colour = Condition)) +
  geom_line(aes(x = Block, y = Value, colour = Condition, group = Condition))
```

[image]

The reason behind this is that `geom_line()` only connects points if it's told they belong to the same data group. [See this link](https://kohske.wordpress.com/2010/12/27/faq-geom_line-doesnt-draw-lines/) for more information. And if you want the exact colours that you specified, you can indicate these manually with `scale_color_manual()`, which I think is what you're after:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = Block, y = Value, colour = Condition)) +
  geom_line(aes(x = Block, y = Value, colour = Condition, group = Condition)) +
  scale_color_manual(values=c("red", "blue", "yellow"))
```

[image]